# Replace Java code with javascript to encrypt in AES/ECB/Pkcs5

Tags: javascript, java, encryption, cryptography, aes

I am coding in node.js where i want to use AES/ECB/Pkcs5 for encrypting my string with a particular key. Now i have java code which is given below but as i tried to code the same thing in javascript things became really messy, Firstly i saw a simple solution of using crypto whose code is given below and i tried it but the output i got was different from the one i got from java, then i switched from crypto to Crypto-js which is another library for encryption now i gain tried the same but i again got different output and then finally when i saw plethora of posts where one said to declare iv and the other one to use key and input_string as a buffer and the other one to use chunks to encrypt the data.

Now as you can imagine i have tried for two days straight to code all these possibilities but none of them worked out, now can anyone please enlighten me and tell me which is the right approach or where i am missing something.

Thanks

**JAVA CODE**

```
SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), "AES");
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
cipher.init(1, secretKeySpec);
byte[] aBytes = cipher.doFinal(inputString.getBytes());
BASE64Encoder encoder = new BASE64Encoder();
String base64 = encoder.encode(aBytes).toString();
base64 = URLEncoder.encode(base64, "UTF-8");
return base64;
```

**CRYPTO-JS CODE**

```
var encrypted = CryptoJS.DES.encrypt(input_string, key, {
    mode: CryptoJS.mode.ECB,
    padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
});

var base64 = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.toString(encrypted.ciphertext);
//      var base64 = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(encrypted);
var parsedStr = base64.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);

console.log('parsedStr: ', parsedStr);
```

**Crypto CODE**

```
var cipher = crypto.createCipher('aes-128-ecb', key);
var crypted = cipher.update(input_string,'utf8','base64')
crypted += cipher.final('base64');
```

**Chunks Implementation**

```
var crypto = require('crypto'),
        iv = new Buffer(''),
        key = new Buffer('abcgthdbgfhyjhuy', 'hex'),
        cipher = cypto.createCipheriv('aes-128-ecb', key, iv),
        chunks = [];

        chunks.push(cipher.update(
            new Buffer(JSON.stringify({key: "abcgthdbgfhyjhuy"}), 'utf8'),
            'buffer', 'base64'));
        chunks.push(cipher.final('base64'));
        var encryptedString = chunks.join('');
        console.log('encryptedString: ', encryptedString);
```

**ONE WHERE I USED input_string AND key AS BUFFER**

```
var key = new Buffer(key, "utf8");
var input_string = new Buffer(input_string, "utf8");
```

**IV USAGE**

```
var key = new Buffer(key, "utf8");
var input_string = new Buffer(input_string, "utf8");
var iv = new Buffer(16); // 16 byte buffer with random data
iv.fill(0); // fill with zeros
var cipher = crypto.createCipher('aes-128-ecb', key, iv);
var crypted = cipher.update(input_string,'utf8','base64')
crypted += cipher.final('base64');
```

Comment: It certainly helps if you have a clue what you are doing. AES is not DES and ECB doesn't use an IV, to name just two *very basic* issues.

Comment: yea i know that AES dont use IV and AES is not DES, i tried what i got from the answers at SO.

Comment: Developing crypto != stitching code together. Even if it works, it's probably not secure, which kind of is the point of doing crypto in the first place.

Comment: there were many answers on SO to do encryption using crypto, that's why i tried to use it, anways can you tell me how can i do above thing in javascript.

Comment: @PrakashKumar https://www.npmjs.com/package/aes-cross  go through this..